# how to reduce test execution time of nose2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, testing, nose2

In order to test our jenkins shared library code we wrote >300 tests.

Each tests run via jenkinsfile runner command, test validate the exit status and console output.

Each tests run ~ 40-60 sec, so the total CI time is ~ 60 min. (we are using jenkins for CI)

We are using python nose2 to run our tests and generate the report xml file.

The nose2 configured to run in parallel of 5 tests. (increase the parallel number not reduce the total CI time )

The 1 hour for CI is too long and I can't find any way how to reduce it.

Does nose2 support distribution tests execution (to run tests on different nodes) or any other solution that will reduce CI time?

Comment: Jenkins has the possibility to execute stages on different agents. Have you tried to split up your tests somehow and let different agents work on them?

Comment: this is exactly the question how to split tests on different agents and than collect all report and present it in test report of jenkins